# Area of ​convex regular polygons

Tags: geometry, polygons

Problem statement:
$a)$ Show that the supreme of the areas of the convex regular polygons with prefixed perimeter p, is given by the area of the corresponding circle with perimeter p.
$b)$ Show that between such polygons the greater the number of sides, the greater the area.

I can't solve this problem. I have tested the following:

$a)$ Using the formula for the area of a regular polygon and the Pythagorean theorem, I have arrived at that the area is

$$A(\theta(N)) = \frac{p \cdot l}{4 \tan(\theta(N))} $$

where  $\theta(N)=\frac{360}{2N}$ ,  p is the perimeter and l de lenght of a side.
I think the best way would be to take limits when N tends to infinity but I would not know how to do it.

$b)$ As the function $ A (\theta) $ is differentiable, I think it would be best to study monotony and see that it is increasing. But I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: You use $N$ in your formula, but you don't say what it means. If it's the number of sides, then isn't the perimeter just $N$ times the length of a side? Seems inconsistent with your formula.

Comment: N is the number of sides.

Comment: When you say "I would not know how to do it", can you elaborate on what you mean? IE A) Do you not know how to take limit for any sequence? B) Do you not know how to take limits for trigonometric sequences? C) Do you not know how to take limits for this particular function? D) Something else. $\quad$ Ditto for part b's "I wouldn't know how to do it".